# disable multicast and promiscuity is off, nic still receive multicast packet

Tags: centos, ipv6, multicast

````
[root@VM-0-13-centos ~]# ip link set dev eth0 multicast off
[root@VM-0-13-centos ~]# 
[root@VM-0-13-centos ~]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:b1:26:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.0.13/24 brd 172.16.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:feb1:26bf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[root@VM-0-13-centos ~]# 
[root@VM-0-13-centos ~]# 
[root@VM-0-13-centos ~]# ip -d link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 promiscuity 0 minmtu 0 maxmtu 0 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:b1:26:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 minmtu 68 maxmtu 65535 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 ```
````

**promiscuity is off, multicast is off**

nic receive a multicast mac(**33:33:00:01:02**), but centos still deal with this packet, **not drop**.
what is the reason?

Comment: I tried this between two real NICs (no paravirtualized VM NIC as OP's case, considering the MAC address) and got as result that multicast is not received anymore (but can still be emitted, since emitting requires not much, only receiving is special). Command on peers: `socat STDIO UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.1.0.1:6666,bind=:6666,ip-add-membership=224.1.0.1:eth0` (ref: https://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-multicast.html ). So Linux behavior is ok, specific behavior for this (VM's) NIC might not be ok.